# python mock global function that is used in class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I can't seem to get my head around mocking in Python. I have a global function:

a.py:

```
def has_permission(args):
    ret_val = ...get-true-or-false...
    return ret_val
```

b.py:

```
class MySerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

     def get_fields():
         fields = super().get_fields()
         for f in :
             if has_permission(...):
                 ret_val[f.name] = fields[f]
         return ret_val
```

c.py:

```
class CountrySerializer(MySerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
```

**Question**: Now i want to test c.py, but i want to mock the **has_permission** function that is defined in a.py, but is called in the get_fields-method of the class MySerializer that is defined in b.py ... How do i do that?

I've tried things like:

```
@patch('b.MySerializer.has_permission')
```

and

```
@patch('b.MySerializer.get_fields.has_permission')
```

and

```
@patch('a.has_permission')
```

But everything i try either just doesn't work and has_permission is still executed, or python complains about that it can't find the attribute 'has_permission'

with the patching done in:

test.py

```
class TestSerializerFields(TestCase):
    @patch(... the above examples....)
    def test_my_country_serializer():
        s = CountrySerializer()
        self..assertTrue(issubclass(my_serializer_fields.MyCharField, type(s.get_fields()['field1'])))
```

Comment: Where are you applying the `patch`?

Comment: @vks: in a test, presumably.

Comment: `@patch('b.MySerializer.has_permission')` is wrong because the `has_permission` function does not in any way belong to the class. what you pass to `patch` is an import path. the subtlety is that, although defined in `a.py, once you've imported it in `b.py` it is also importable from `b.py` ...and it's the copy imported in `b.py` that you want to patch

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to patch the global in the `b` module:

```
@patch('b.has_permission')
```

because that's where your code looks for it.

Also see the [*Where to patch* section](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) of the `mock` documentation.

Comment: Tnx... That was it! If i understand correctly, then patch('b.has_permission') patches all calls to has_permission defined *anywhere* in the whole b.py file?

Comment: @RvL: it replaces the `has_permission` object you imported into the module, yes. All code using `has_permission` always uses the same global object.

Comment: @RvL: you cannot patch the use of a global for just one function.

Comment: Ahh it is starting to make sense to me now. Tnx :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to patch the method where it exists at the time your test runs.  If you try and patch the method where it is defined after the test code has already imported it, then the patch will have no effect.  At the point where the `@patch(...)` executes, the test code under test has already grabbed the global method into its own module.

Here is an example:

#### `app/util/config.py`:

```
# This is the global method we want to mock
def is_search_enabled():
    return True
```

#### `app/service/searcher.py`:

```
# Here is where that global method will be imported 
#  when this file is first imported
from app.util.config import is_search_enabled

class Searcher:
    def __init__(self, api_service):
        self._api_service = api_service

    def search(self):
        if not is_search_enabled():
            return None
        return self._api_service.perform_request('/search')
```

#### `test/service/test_searcher.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock
# The next line will cause the imports of `searcher.py` to execute...
from app.service.searcher import Searcher
# At this point, searcher.py has imported is_search_enabled into its module.
# If you later try and patch the method at its definition 
#  (app.util.config.is_search_enabled), it will have no effect because 
#  searcher.py won't look there again.

class MockApiService:
    pass

class TestSearcher:

    # By the time this executes, `is_search_enabled` has already been
    #  imported into `app.service.searcher`.  So that is where we must
    #  patch it.
    @patch('app.service.searcher.is_search_enabled')
    def test_no_search_when_disabled(self, mock_is_search_enabled):
        mock_is_search_enabled.return_value = False
        mock_api_service = MockApiService()
        mock_api_service.perform_request = Mock()
        searcher = Searcher(mock_api_service)

        results = searcher.search()

        assert results is None
        mock_api_service.perform_request.assert_not_called()

    # (For completeness' sake, make sure the code actually works when search is enabled...)
    def test_search(self):
        mock_api_service = MockApiService()
        mock_api_service.perform_request = mock_perform_request = Mock()
        searcher = Searcher(mock_api_service)
        expected_results = [1, 2, 3]
        mock_perform_request.return_value = expected_results

        actual_results = searcher.search()

        assert actual_results == expected_results
        mock_api_service.perform_request.assert_called_once_with('/search')
```

Comment: God bless you, man! Your reply solved my problem which took me two days to solve.